# How to iterate across views & remove views based on condition

Tags: android

Currently I want to do something like this

```
FrameLayout parent = ...

for (childView in parent)
{
    if (satisfyPredicate(childView))
    {
        removeFromParent(childView);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this in android (since I am mutating the list as I go)

Requirements:

- Cannot remove all views and reinflate all views (views contains pictures and such an algorithm would cause the UI to flicker oddly)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off-  if you want to walk a list and mutate it, you can easily.  Just use a do, while, or old style for loop from i=0 to parent.getChildCount() 
 instead of a foreach loop or an iterator.

Secondly-  you probably don't want to remove the views, especially if you may see them later.  You probably want to set their visibility to GONE (GONE views are not drawn to the screen and do not take up space, but will remain in the view hierarchy).

Comment: I do want them gone, and also can you give a pseudocode an example about what you said with a do while loop? Thanks